# What's Lagrangian multiplier and when to use it?

Tags: matrix-equations, lagrange-multiplier

I have this equation $ e^TCe $ with $ e^Te = 1 $ which i want to apply on it lagrange multiplier, how to do it (with steps please)
Also how to take the derivative of the lagrangian ?

EDIT : lagrange multiplier is used to create L then derivative of L is calculated with : $\partial L / \partial e$

EDIT2 : C $ \in R^{d*d} $ and e is $ \in R^{p*d} $

EDIT3 :

$$\eqalign{
 L &= e^TCe - \lambda(e^Te-1) \cr
dL
 &= de^TCe + e^TC\,de - 2\lambda e^T\,de   \quad (1) \cr 
 &= e^TC^T\,de + e^TC\,de - 2\lambda e^T\,de \quad (2) \cr
 &= 2e^TC\,de - 2\lambda e^T\,de \cr
 &= 2(Ce-\lambda e)^T\,de \cr
\frac{\partial L}{\partial e} &= 2(Ce-\lambda e) \cr
}$$

But still can't understand why to go from line (1) to (2) ?
THanks

Comment: Lagrange multipliers is very different from a "Lagrangian." The former is used to optimize (find the maxima and minima of) a function of multiple variables subject to a constraint.  I'm not sure what you mean by "take the derivative of a Lagrangian."

Comment: see my edit pls

Comment: The Lagrangian is $\mathcal L(u)=u^TSu+\lambda\left(1-u^Tu \right)$ See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). Knowing the dimensions of the matrices/vectors  is useful.

Comment: How you do this pls explain and how to calculate its derivative ( to u)

Comment: What are the properties of $\textbf u$ and $\textbf S$? I´m sure you´ve omitted some information.

Comment: u is a unit vector and S is a covariance matrix

Comment: why did @callculus remove his answer pls?

Comment: I´ve trouble with the dimensions. If you meanwhile want to work on deratives of matrices look [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf) on p.9, second order.

Comment: ALright no problem

Comment: Is $\textbf 1$ a matrix with all ones or is it a matrix with ones on the diagonal only.

Comment: u is a unit vector, 1 is the value 1

Comment: It cannot be just 1 since $u^tu$ has the dimensions $d\times d$.

Comment: Yes it's 1 in d-dimensions, see my third EDIT pls

Comment: Please add the dimension of e and C.

Comment: see EDIT2 please

Comment: I go for a walk and will be back in approx. 2 hours-before it´s getting dark. If no answer has been posted I will try.

Comment: thanks so much, just the pass from equivalence (1) to (2) see (EDIT3)

Comment: @Sam Meanwhile check the dimensions of $e^Te$. If $e$ has the dimensions $p \times d$, then $e^Te$ has the dimensions $d \times d$. So your $1$ should has the dimensions $d \times d$ as well. But what kind of matrix is it? A identity matrix or a matrix with all ones or something else?

Comment: a matrix with all ones